# apache mod_rewrite not working with mod proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, ruby-on-rails, mod-proxy

I have a Rails 2.3.18 application running on `http://0.0.0.0:3004/`, it is running with **Passenger module**, and is deploying on Apache server with **proxy module** using the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Proxy *>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/my/app/public
    <Directory /path/to/my/app/public>
        Options +FolowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [P]
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3004/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3004/
</VirtualHost>
```

In the configuration I put the following rule of **Rewrite module**:

`RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [P]`

This would redirect all request that goes to `http://mydomain.com/folder/...` to `http://mydomain.com/...` but the rule is not working because.

For example, I request the images from:

```
http://mydomain.com/folder/images/image.jpg
```

the objective is to redirect to

```
http://mydomain.com/images/image.jpg
```

but it is not working, it always uses the first path.

Thank you very much.

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests don't begin with folder, they begin with a forward slash.

```
RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)$ /$1 [P]
```